# Is github providing any kind of real time repos list?

Tags: github

yesterday i uploaded security decoding key on github public repositories for a mistake 
(must be upload private repositories) and today i recognize that i had mistake.
is github providing any kind of real time repositories list?
i worry about this so much (Sorry about bad English)

Comment: Change any keys or passwords you uploaded. Even if you delete the repo altogether, they have been publicized.

Answer (score 1):

Github actually has a helpful [guide](https://help.github.com/en/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository) on how to remove sensitive information from a repository.

However, please note what they have to say about uploading sensitive data:

> **Warning: Once you have pushed a commit to GitHub, you should consider any data it contains to be compromised.** If you committed a password, change it! If you committed a key, generate a new one.

That being said, you can try using [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) to purge any sensitive data.